# Need more than 2 datasets for “Execute R Script” module in “Azure Machine Learning Studio”

Tags: r, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

Since connecting to Azure SQL database from “Execute R Script” module in “Azure Machine Learning Studio” is not possible, and using Import Data modules (a.k.a Readers) is the only recommended approach, my question is that what can I do when I need more than 2 datasets as input for "Execute R Script module"?

```
// I'm already doing the following to get first 2 datasets,
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)
dataset2 <- maml.mapInputPort(2)
```

How can I "import" a dataset3?

Comment: And what if I need 3 datasets from 3 different Azure DB sources? does that become completely impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is combining two data-sets together and selecting the appropriate fields using the R script. That would be an easy workaround.

Comment: if I may follow up with a question: what's the recommended way to combine two datasets together using SQL in "Import Modules"? an example? just a straight "SELECT table_1_columns, table_2_columns from table_1 UNION table_2"?

Comment: Exactly. You can do that